# How to access all intents created inside a bot in amazon lex?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am using amazon lex for creating custom bots.. Inside bot i have created many intents. can we find all the intents that are created inside a particulat bot, for example like currentIntent will display that particular intent i want to print all the existing intents in a bot

Answer (score 1):

You will not find all of the intents listed in the Lex Request, only the `currentIntent` is passed by Lex to your backend Lambda function.

So you must use the Amazon Lex API, specifically the [LexModelBuildingService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexModelBuildingService.html), where you can add to, change, or get the bot's model set up.

To get started using the Lex Model Building Service in Node.js, follow these instructions:  [AWS SDK for JavaScript >> Getting Started in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/getting-started-nodejs.html#getting-started-nodejs-download)

After you have installed the AWS SDK for JavaScript, you can use the LexModelBuildingService like this:

```
var lexmodelbuildingservice = new AWS.LexModelBuildingService();
```

Then you will want to use the [GetIntents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_GetIntents.html) action.

> **GetIntents**
>   Returns intent information as follows:
>     - If you specify the nameContains field, returns the $LATEST version of all intents that contain the specified string.
>     - If you don't specify the nameContains field, returns information about the $LATEST version of all intents.

Use the `getIntents` action like this:

```
var params = {
  maxResults: 50,  //set to how many intents you think your bot has
  nextToken: ""
};
```

First set the parameters but don't include a `nameContains` field so you get all Intents back instead of just one. Then invoke getIntents like this:

```
lexmodelbuildingservice.getIntents(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) { console.log(err, err.stack); }
   else {
       // handle data here
   }
});
```

That `function(err, data)` is the callback function that will run when `getIntents` is finished retrieving the Intents information which will be provided as `data`.

This is how the `data` object will be formatted:

```
{
   "intents": [ 
      { 
         "createdDate": number,
         "description": "string",
         "lastUpdatedDate": number,
         "name": "string",
         "version": "string"
      }
   ],
   "nextToken": "string"
}
```

Use the `nextToken` if there are more intents than your set `maxResults`, to get the next page of intents information.

So to get all of the names of all of the intents, here's how to handle the data in the above code where it says "handle data here". You will want to loop through the `intents` array and create your own array of all the names.

```
var intents = data.intents;
var intentNames = [];
for (i=0; i<intents.length; i++) {
    intentNames[i] = intents[i].name;
}
```

So in the end, your Lambda node.js code should look something like:

```
var lexmodelbuildingservice = new AWS.LexModelBuildingService();

var params = {
  maxResults: 50,
  nextToken: ""
};

lexmodelbuildingservice.getIntents(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) { console.log(err, err.stack); }
    else {
        var intents = data.intents;
        var intentNames = [];
        for (i=0; i<intents.length; i++) {
            intentNames[i] = intents[i].name;
        }

    // intentNames is now an array of intent names, do with it as you like here.
    }
});
```

Comment: none of these would work because OP wants to get all the intents of a particular Bot.

Comment: for checking i can see on left side of lex, but i need to send it to backend all the intents available in lex

Comment: @praveenDp the 1st method that Jay mentioned will give you list of all the intents which you can send to backend

Comment: @sid8491 but how to include that request in nodejs lambda?

Comment: @praveenDp using getIntents() function from node js model building services https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexModelBuildingService.html#getIntents-property

Comment: @paveenDp I've updated my answer for your specific needs, including how to create an array of the intent names from the data you get back from 'getIntents'